# Scaled viewport not working in libgdx Stage

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport, stage

I have a simple stage with one button and 3 cells:

```
pauseStage = new Stage(screen.game.viewport);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(pauseStage);
pauseTable = new Table();
pauseTable.setFillParent(true);
pauseTable.debug();

Button.ButtonStyle musicBtnStyle = new Button.ButtonStyle();
musicBtnStyle.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion((Texture)     this.screen.game.assetManagement.manager.get("MenuScreen/music_up.png")));
    musicBtnStyle.down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion((Texture) this.screen.game.assetManagement.manager.get("MenuScreen/music_down.png")));
    musicButton = new Button(musicBtnStyle);
    musicButton.addListener(new ClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y)
        {


        }
    });

pauseTable.row();
pauseTable.add().expandX();
pauseTable.add(musicButton).size(230f,230f);
pauseTable.add().expandX();

pauseTable.pack();
pauseStage.addActor(pauseTable);
```

`screen.game.viewport` is declared as `viewport = new FitViewport(2560,1440, camera)`. With this code the stage is rendered fine.

[not scaled viewvport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G26Rt.png)

If I am using a scaled viewport, `viewport = new FitViewport(25.6,14.4, camera)` and I am changing the cell size to 2.3 from 230 ...

```
pauseTable.add(musicButton).size(2.3f,2.3f);
```

... the stage is not rendered correctly. The button and the cell are displaced, as you can see it below:

[scaled viewport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMIio.png)

Does anyone know, why is it not working with a scaled viewport?

Comment: Could we see where the viewport is being updated and created? And screen.game should not be a thing. Game should not belong to screen, screen should belong to game. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: Hi Lucas! You are right, screen should belong to game, ad that is how I carried it out. My game holds the screens, but I am passing my game to my screens, otherwise how could I trigger it's switch_screen method? This is my viewport update: if (pauseScreen.pauseStage != null) {
   pauseScreen.pauseStage.getViewport().update(width, height);
  }

Comment: pauseScreen itself is not a screen, it is only a class where I am creating a stage for the pause menu. It's parent (Act1Screen) is implementing Screen and I am calling the above code in it's resize method:  public void resize(int width, int height) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  viewportBackground.update(width, height);
  viewportScene.update(width, height);
  HUD.getViewport().update(width, height);
  if (pauseScreen.pauseStage != null) {
   pauseScreen.pauseStage.getViewport().update(width, height);
  }
 }

Comment: I know, I had passed game to screen before I made a big environment static class that was global and held all my game references. So do that, make a class which holds a static game instance,  and then you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: What is viewportBackground and viewportScene?

Comment: viewportBackground = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, cameraBackground);
viewportScene = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, cameraScene);
viewportMenu = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, cameraMenu);

viewportBackground displays the background image
viewportScene displays the level bodies
viewportMenu displays the HUD, pause button, score etc